# GNU/Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezes when using function keys

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 20.04

I've recently began using ubuntu again in a long time *(I used 16.04 LTS 3 years ago)* , I've installed ubuntu on my **Dell Inspirion 17 5748** , and everything worked great,except for some random screen tearing when scrolling *(also not just because dell has a ubuntu option when buying from them)*, but when I use the **fn keys**, like for brightness, search, sound, ubuntu just **Freezes for no reason** , **wait for 15 - 30 seconds** and everything is back to normal. In my **4 years of linux** experiences, I've never, **ever** encountred anything like this. If someone has a soloution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but on a Huawei laptop and it doesn't freeze so long, maybe 2 or 3 seconds